# show category and subcategories in a tree menu using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, categories

I want to show categories and subcategories like a tree menu:

**Category**

- Subcategory
- Subcategory 2

**Category 2**

- Subcategory
- Subcategory 2

my database contains 3 colomns:

categoryId, categoryName, categoryParentId

I really don't have an idea how to do this?! Can somebody help me?! I found some codes on the net, but I couldn't make them work

Answer (score 1):

The best way to make such a structure would be to implement either an **Adjacency List model** or **Nested Set model**. You can read more about them [in this excellent article](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) by Mike Hillyer.

Of course, you can always come up with a home-made solution, but in my experience, they often don't come up as good, effective and flexible as the two mentioned above.